# Is there a function or tool for filling a database with a CSV file using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hana

I got a connection to the SAP HANA database. I've created a personal DB called simply "database" which I want to fill with two CSV files that I have in my laptop.

How can I do this? 
Do I need to create the tables with the all the columns before?

One of the problem is that my CSV files are composed by 130 columns. 
It is impossible to create all the columns from scratch.

Thank you in advance for you help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this out [Import CSV into SAP HANA, express edition using the SAP HANA Tools for Eclipse](https://developers.sap.com/tutorials/mlb-hxe-import-data-eclipse.html)

Comment: Could you post an excerpt of the external hyperlink please? Otherwise the question will have no interest for future visitors if the external hyperlink disappears, as it is currently the case.​

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the **import data from front end** function in SAP HANA Studio for that.

The wizard lets you define the target table structure based on the data found in the CSV files.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you mean. I'm working on the Eclipse workspace where a connection to HANA has been established. Now I can write SQL script for creating tables etc, but I want just to import into the DB my CSV. I'm not working in SAP HANA Studio. Maybe I didn't understand what you mean so sorry for that.

Comment: Oh, I'm using SAP Cloud Platform.

Comment: When using Eclipse you should installed the SAP HANA tools for eclipse (https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/#hanatools) which provide the HANA studio features in your Eclipse IDE.

Comment: In that’s case you could’ve just followed my initial answer which is exactly the same approach that the tutorial page explains.